# -NaN in printf in C

Tags: c, printf, nan

I am currently experiencing issues with a Raytracer "Engine" in some calculations.

```
  info->eyex = -1000.0;
  info->eyey = 0.0;
  printf("%f et %f et %f et %f et %f\n", info->eyex, info->vx, info->eyey, info->vy, info->vz);
```

For example, in that piece of code, values seems good, but `info->eyex` gives me a `-nan` error.

It's weird, because I reset the value before.

Comment: Since printf subverts the type system, you need to specify what type the variables are when you ask a question about printf.

Comment: `-nan` probably means you have a division by zero.

Comment: @Paul He assigns the variable and then immediately passes it to printf.

Comment: @Unlimited: You should post the `info` class definition.

Comment: @Unlimited: Also it may be helpful: `%f` can be treated as `float`; try to use `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: @artyom.stv: In printf and other varargs functions, float is automatically promoted to double. It's `scanf` where `%lf` matters.

Comment: @artyom: the `printf` conversion specifier `"%lf"` is not described by the Standard. Compilers are allowed to define what it does as an extension ... and programs that use that specific extension are therefore severely limited in portability.

Comment: IMHO to help Unlimited with this question we still need to know `info` type definition.

Comment: what is the type of info->eyex

Answer (score 4):

My psychic sense tells me that `eyex` is declared as an `int`, not as a `double` as it should be.  When you assign -1000.0 to it, it gets truncated to the integer -1000 (your compiler *should* give you a warning here), which is represented in binary as 0xFFFFFC18 using two's complement notation.  Likewise, assuming that `eye` is also an integer, its value of 0 is represented in binary as 0x00000000.

When you pass `eyex`, `eyey`, and the other parameters to `printf`, they get pushed on the stack so that they lie in memory with increasing addresses.  So immediately before the `call` instruction to call the subroutine, the stack frame looks something like this:

```
<top of stack>
0xFFFFFC18   ; eyex
(4-8 bytes)  ; vx
0x00000000   ; eyey
(4-8 bytes)  ; vy
(4-8 bytes)  ; vz
```

When `printf` sees the `%f` format specifier, that says "take 8 bytes off of the stack, interpret them as a `double` value, and print out that `double` value".  So it sees the value 0xFFFFFC18xxxxxxxx, where the xxxxxxxxx is the value of `info->vx`.  Regardless of that value, this is the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) representation of NaN, or "not a number".  It has the sign bit set, so some implementations may choose to interpret this as "negative NaN", though this has the same semantics as regular NaN.

Your compiler should also be warning you here that you're passing the wrong types of arguments to `printf`—it's expecting a `double` but you're not passing it that.  GCC enables these warnings with `-Wall`, which I highly recommend enabling.

So, the solution is to declare `eyex` to be of type `double` (and presumably the other variables to also be `double`, if they're not already).  Alternatively, if you don't control the definition of `eyex` et al (say, because they're part of a structure for a third-party library), then what you should instead be doing is printing them out with the `%d` modifier to print them as integers, not with `%f`, and you should also assign them integer values such as -1000 and 0, not floating-point values such as -1000.0 and 0.0.

Comment: I thought floats get promoted to doubles when passed to vararg functions. Everything else in this post is gold.

Comment: @MSN: Yes, floats do get promoted to doubles when passed to variadic functions.  Where did I say anything to the contrary?

Comment: that stack layout you posted implies that the floats are pushed as 4 bytes. The int will be, but the floats would be pushed as 8 bytes.

Comment: @MSN: Ah ok, I see what you mean.  We don't actually know the data types of `vx`, `vy`, or `vz` either.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm this. I don't know exactly what triggers that behavior, though. printf is optimized at compile time, and the format string analyzed. Probably it's (wrongly) assuming something about your variable. Even though %f should work for doubles and floats, it seems it doesn't always (at least with gcc 4.4.5, which is the one I'm using)

Try assigning the value to another variable and then passing that to printf. Although ugly, that solved the problem for me.